# Referenced assembly references

Tags: .net

If assembly A (which is executable) references assembly B, should it reference all assembly B's references (even if it doesn't use classes which use these references)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: There is now a certain amount of confusion about the circumstances under which indirect references are copied into the output folder of the "main" project. It may well depend on the version of Visual Studio, aside from anything else. Visual Studio 2010 appears to use a certain amount of intelligence in working out which indirectly referenced assemblies might actually be used - but the exact logic is a mystery to me at the moment.

*If* in your situation all the required assemblies end up being copied, then you might as well leave your list of references short - but it's probably worth looking at whether some indirect references are missing, and whether they're important to you or not. In particular, any references which are *present* in B but only loaded by reflection may not end up being copied...

---

**Older answer**

Not *necessarily* - if it doesn't use any functionality in B which needs the other references *even indirectly* then it's fine not to add the extra references. However, this means relying on the implementation details of which features in B require which extra references. I think it's typically safer to add all the references unless there are very clear guidelines from the provider of B as to which references are needed in which cases.

EDIT: Just to be clear, you don't *have* to add references, so long as `B` has all the assemblies it needs available at execution time. The simplest way to make sure they all get copied along with `A` is to add references to `A`. It's more of a deployment simplification than anything else. If `B`'s references are being loaded from the GAC anyway (not something I personally like) then it won't matter at all; if they're being loaded locally but you're willing to copy the files explicitly into the deployment folder, that's fine too... but adding the assemblies to the list of `A`'s assembly references is simpler. (I think it's logical, too - they're still assemblies `A` needs in order to execute correctly, even though it's an indirect requirement.)

Comment: Could you please clarify why you think "it's typically safer to add all the references unless there are very clear guidelines...". In my projects, I typically add just the **minimal necessary** set of references - is there a specific situation in which adding a reference I don't use would be beneficial?

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic, if assembly B implementation changes (requiring reference out of "minimal necessary" set), your application will throw runtime exception

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I'm not sure I follow. As long as B keeps its interface stable, it shouldn't matter if it adds one more "sub-reference", right? If B's interface changes, you'll have to amend the EXE anyway, reference or no reference. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Branko: If the implementation of something in B starts using a new dependency, even without changing the public interface, you'll have to add a reference otherwise the implementation will fail at execution time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I don't think that's correct. Let's say you have an assembly B with `ClassB` and assembly C with `ClassC`. If in your EXE you say: `var b = new ClassB()`, so you'll need to reference B from EXE but not C. Now add public `ClassC GetC() { /*...*/ }` to `ClassB`. This requires B to reference C, but EXE is still **not** required to reference C. Only if you actually call `GetC()` in EXE will you be required to reference C from the EXE. So even interface can change without requiring any new references (as long as it changes in the part you don't use), let alone implementation.

Comment: @Branko, but what if GetC is called inside ClassB constructor, for example?

Comment: @Idsa, Nothing would happen. I would still **not** need to reference C from the EXE.

Comment: @Branko: Assembly C still needs to be present though - see my edit. Hopefully that will resolve our differences.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, as long as there is a reference to C **at some level**, the C will be available at run-time. The Visual Studio will recursively copy all references to 'bin' folder (including C, even if not directly referenced by A). Same happens to Setup (MSI) projects. So, how do surplus references represents a "deployment simplification"? Cold you please point me to a specific case where surplus references bring a direct benefit (preferably one that outweighs the extra maintenance burden imposed)? *BTW thanks for the effort, but as you can see, I'm still not convinced, sorry ;)*

Comment: @Branko: No, Visual Studio doesn't copy references recursively. Certainly not in my experience, anyway. It may do so for MSI projects - I haven't done any setup for a long time. I'll double check this later on, but I *know* I've run into problems where I've had A reference B, B reference C but not A reference C, and C hasn't ended up in the output folder.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I tried under Visual Studio 2010 and it **does** copy references recursively. BTW, this is true whether B is a Visual Studio "class library" project or just an assembly without a corresponding project (or source for that matter). Not sure about older VS versions though...

Comment: @Branko Odd. I'll try it myself tonight. You wouldn't always want all of the references...just some. I'm 90% sure older versions didn't do this but I can't check right now. Will edit when I've checked itmyself and when I'm not on the beach...

Comment: @Branko: I've just tried it with C# Express 2010 (all I've got on the netbook I'm using at the moment) and it *didn't* copy the reference recursively. Do you have something like ReSharper or CodeRush which might be doing it for you? Or perhaps there's an option somewhere?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I also tried it and got the same result as Branko. Created this question to clarify things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215004/rules-of-referenced-assemblies-copying

Comment: @Jon Skeet, just to make sure, I installed a fresh Visual C# 2010 Express into a clean virtual machine and recursive references **did** get copied (I did not change any options after the installation). BTW, I do have the ReSharper on my actual development machine - I can uninstall it and give it another try if you think it would be helpful, but I doubt it will make any difference.

Comment: BTW, I posted a C# Express screenshot as an answer to stackoverflow.com/questions/7215004/

Comment: @Branko: Weird. I've double-checked, and it simply doesn't happen on my box. What sort of project did you create (as Project A)?

Comment: @Branko: Okay, I've now added code in B which actually *uses* C, and suddenly it *is* copied. Very odd. Will edit this answer...

Comment: @Branko: I've now added my own answer to the other question. In most cases it'll be fine (as most of the time referenced assemblies *will* be used) but just occasionally only reflection will be used - and a reference isn't enough.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, yup I agree on reflection. However, adding a surplus root-level reference will not help us with that, which was the gist of the original question.

Comment: @Branko: No, a surplus root-level reference *will* fix that, as it *will* copy the assembly in the case, regardless of code. Direct references are always copied. However, I agree that's an edge case.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I stand corrected. You are right, the direct reference gets copied even when it is not actually used. The indirect reference gets copied only if it is actually used. Huh, I'm glad we got to the bottom of this ;)

Comment: @Branko: Me too - I've definitely learned a lot about indirect references :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is any possibility that any of the indirectly-referenced assemblies is in the GAC on your build machine, but won't be in the GAC at runtime, then you should add explicit references to those indirectly-referenced assemblies and set CopyLocal=True. This is because indirectly-referenced assemblies that are in the GAC won't be copied to the bin folder. More details in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26421019/1208980).