# Rules of referenced assemblies copying

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Which rules does VS (msbuild?) follow during solution build? In which cases it will copy indirectly referenced asemblies to output folder and in which not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've just been a bit of experimentation, and it looks like any indirectly referenced assembly which has a type *directly referenced by code* in another assembly will be copied. If there's nothing in code, it won't be. Here's my sample scenario:

- MainProgram: Console application with a direct reference to DirectAssembly. Code in Main:

  ```
  var foo = new DirectAssembly.SampleClass();
  ```
- DirectAssembly: Class library with a direct reference to IndirectAssembly. Contains `SampleClass`:

  ```
  public class SampleClass
  {
      // Comment out this line to change the behaviour...
      IndirectAssembly.IndirectClass neverUsed = null;

      public SampleClass()
      {
          object x = Activator.CreateInstance("IndirectAssembly",
                                              "IndirectAssembly.IndirectClass");

      }
  }
  ```
- IndirectAssembly: Contains a public class `IndirectClass` with a public parameterless constructor

As described above, it works because IndirectAssembly is copied into the output folder of MainProgram. If you comment out the line indicated in SampleClass, IndirectAssembly is *not* copied (even though it's still a reference) and the code will fail at execution time.

I'm not saying these are *all* the rules, but they're at least a start...

Comment: +1 If types from other assemblies are directly referenced, they will be copied. I have had on occasion to explicitly reference types, which would normally be loaded dynamically, so that they will be deployed.

Comment: But we shouldn’t have to do this!

Comment: @binki: I agree it's a pain, and with NuGet in ASP.NET 5 it's a lot better. But at least knowing what is reqiured helps...

Answer (score 5):

There is a subtlety not addressed by previous answers, namely whether the referenced assembly is in the GAC.

Consider a project that references assembly A, which in turn depends on assemblies B and C. Assembly C happens to have been installed into the GAC by some "other product". I have found that Visual Studio 2013 copies A and B, but not C, to the output folder, because C is already in the GAC. If I then run the application on a machine that doesn't have "other product" installed, I get a runtime binding failure.

I've also noticed that Microsoft's documentation in this area appears to be wrong, at least for VS2013.

[Managing Project References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew(v=vs.120).aspx) states

> If you deploy an application that contains a reference to a custom component that is registered in the GAC, the component will not be deployed with the application, regardless of the CopyLocal setting. In earlier versions of Visual Studio, you could set the CopyLocal property on a reference to ensure that the assembly was deployed. Now, you must manually add the assembly to the \Bin folder

My tests with VS2013 show that, contrary to the above, CopyLocal=True *always* copies the directly-referenced assembly to the output folder, regardless of whether it's in the GAC. But indirectly-referenced assemblies appear to be copied only if they are not in the GAC.

This behaviour means that to be sure that indirectly-referenced assemblies are deployed with your application you should add explicit references to them, with CopyLocal=True (or manually copy them). Note that by default CopyLocal will be set to False if the assembly is in the GAC.

Answer (score 2):

It should copy all the recursive references. For example:

[image]

**--- EDIT---**

The rules (at least in VS2010) seem to be as follows:

- An indirect reference is copied only if actually used.
- A direct reference is copied no matter what - even if not actually used.

So, if you want to ensure that the assembly required for reflection is deployed, reference it from the root project.

Reflection concerns aside, it seems to be enough to just add the minimal set of references at each level of project hierarchy.

Comment: and what if remove assembly C usage (but keep the reference) from B? It will not copy assembly C. And what if make assembly C usage by reflection? It will not copy assembly C

Comment: @Idsa: Yup - that's just what I was writing up too.

Comment: @Idsa The point about reflection is valid. As for keeping the "unnecessary" reference from B to C, it is true the C will not be copied to `bin`, but there will be **no** run-time error either.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that it copies all directly referenced assemblies, recursively - that is, anything directly referenced in your code, and anything that these reference too.

Anything that is not referenced at compile time in your code will not be referenced. So references that only resolved at run time will not be copied. This is because, even though you may know exactly what it references, the copmpiler doesn't. Whether reflection or using the activator to reference it ( as in the two answers already given ) because at compile time, the actual type of the objects cannot be determined.

The references in the project indicate where code references should be resolved to, but that is all - I think the evidence is that they wil not be copied - it is all based on the compile time coded references.

This is one reason why some of the injection techniques can work, before the resolution of the reference need not be done at the point of compilation or even deployment.